# Play sound every minute

Tags: python

I’m trying to make some code so every so often it plays a random sound, could anyone help? This is what i have so far:

```
import random
from time import sleep
from playsound import playsound

x=quote_list = [quote1, quote2, quote3]

def quote1 ():
    [playsound('/c:users\alex\music\file1.wav', block = False)

def quote2 ():
    [playsound('/c:users\alex\music\file2.wav', block = False)

def quote3 ():
    [playsound('/c:users\alex\music\file3.wav', block = False)

while 10 > 1:
    playsound(x)
```

Comment: Why did you define those functions when you don't use them?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use pygame for this purpose.

```
pygame.mixer.Sound(random.choice(soundfiles)).play()
```

There is a full documentation of this functions:

[Full Documentation](https://pygame.readthedocs.io/en/latest/7_sound/sound.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you don't even need a list for this.
You just need to play a sound and then wait for 60 seconds.

I'll explain the code for you so you understand it, it's simple.

```
while 1:
    playsound("/c:users\alex\music\file" + str(random.randint(1,3)) + ".wav", block = False)
    time.sleep(60)
```

while 1: This repeats your code over and over.

The sound is picked randomly by string concatenation with the `random.randint()` function. (1,3) returns a random integer from 1 to 3. You can change these values to how many sounds you want to choose from. !Note: The file names always has to be the same with just the number changed, otherwise it won't pick your sound file.

Comment: No problem. I would appreciate a verfication for the answer :)